# Set Multiplication

Tags: relations

The question starts with this:

> Given the following relation S on Z×Z  where Z= {a, b, c, d, e}:
> S={(a, a),(b, b),(a, b),(b, a),(c, c),(d, d),(e, e),(c, e),(d, e),(e,
> c),(e, d)}

Then it asks to see if it is an equivalence relation.

I think I'm missing something because doesn't Z x Z =

> {(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(a,e),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(b,d),(b,e),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c),(c,d),(c,e),(d,a),(d,b),(d,c),(d,d),(d,e),(e,a),(e,b),(e,c),(e,d),(e,e)}

Comment: Do you know what an equivalence relation is?

Comment: Note: technically, $S$ is a binary relation on $Z$, not $Z \times Z$.

Comment: A relation $S$ "over Z" is merely a subset of $Z\times Z$.  Your example here... indeed, $S$ *is* a subset of $Z\times Z$ and so is a valid relation over $Z$.  The question is whether or not your relation $S$ satisfies certain "nice" properties that often interest us about relations

Comment: If your complaint is about the phrasing, yes... I would have said $S$ is a relation over $Z$.  It is correct that $S$ is not a subset of $(Z\times Z)\times (Z\times Z)$ and so should not be called "a relation over $Z\times Z$" but it should be clear from context that we intended $S$ to be treated as a relation over $Z$.

Comment: Agreed, but the poster may not understand the subtlety

Comment: Yea sorry guys it wasn't that deep. I actually didn't understand something basic about this. I didn't realize that S was a subset. I thought it meant literally Z X Z = S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation $R$ on a set $T$ is a subset of $T \times T$. Hence the problem in the question totally makes sense as $S$ is indeed a subset of $Z \times Z$.

You're just asked to validate that your relation $S$ satisfies the axioms of an equivalence relation. Namely: reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: OH I guess I missed something extremely important. I didn't realize that S is a subset. I just thought it meant literally Z X Z = S.

Comment: Now you got it I imagine!

Comment: Yes Yes thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Question is whether the relation $S$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

S={(a, a),(b, b),(a, b),(b, a),(c, c),(d, d),(e, e),(c, e),(d, e),(e, c),(e, d)}

Its reflexive and symmetric but not transitive, since $(c,e), (e,d)\in S$ but $(c,d)\not\in S$.